# There doesn't seem to be valid storyboard at path

Tags: ios, storyboard

Am getting a crash when making a transition to another view controller in story board. 
The transition happens on click of a bar button. The crash does not happen every time, it happens only the third or fourth time i repeat the transition.

Am doing the transition from like this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
ScanToMatchViewController *stmVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ScanToMatch"];
stmVC.fieldModel = self.fieldModel;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:stmVC animated:YES];
```

This is when clicking on a bar button on the navigation bar. The bar button is added in code since the navigation bar was not being displayed for the viewcontroller on story board.

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(saveScanClicked)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
```

Any idea of what could be going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are using a storyboard why aren't you using a push segue? It sounds like your storyboard is misconfigured.

Comment: Actually i also need to make the transition on click of an alert view button, here i need to push through code. Also am not getting a navigation bar for this view controller on story board to add a bar button and directly connect that to a segue.

Comment: But that is the misconfiguration I am talking about. If the nav bar is not shown it is because you have not told the storyboard that this view controller is child of a navigation controller. The error is telling you the storyboard is invalid, remember?

Comment: I am suggesting you remove this vc from the storyboard and design its view in a xib instead. That way you can instantiate it with no reference to a storyboard.

Comment: Oh ok, i never thought about creating viewcontrollers using seperate xib files, i used to just leave them dangling on storyboards without any segue connection, i will try out your point. Thanks

Comment: I'm not saying I understand the source of the specific problem, but what I'm suggesting you do is what I do, and I've never had this "no valid storyboard" error in my life. For the technique I'm describing, see this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_in_a_separate_nib